# import database errors were found during analysis

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, mariadb

Static analysis:

8 errors were found during analysis.

```
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "MariaDB" at position 0)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "dump" at position 8)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10.17" at position 13)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "Distrib" at position 20)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "10.4" at position 28)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near ".13" at position 32)
Unexpected beginning of statement. (near "MariaDB" at position 36)
Unrecognized statement type. (near "for" at position 45)
```

SQL query:

```
MariaDB dump 10.17 Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) -- -- Host: localhost Database: raouf_wp_vfiq5 -- ------------------------------------------------------ -- Server version 10.4.13-MariaDB /*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */
```

MySQL said: Documentation

### #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'MariaDB dump 10.17  Distrib 10.4.13-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64)

-- Host: l...' at line 1

How to find a solution!!

Comment: the first line of the file should have `--` as the start to indicate it too is a comment.

Comment: Show the command you were trying to run _and the context in which you were trying to run it_.